# window.Web3 is missing in Mist

Tags: web3js, mist, bug

When I open the below HTML code in Mist 0.11.1 the popup shows empty that is `window.Web3` is undefined!

How to make `window.Web3` to work in Mist?

My code similar to this works in MetaMask but not in Mist.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Web3</title>
<script>
alert(window.Web3);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I experiment on Ubuntu Linux 18.10.

---

Well, a real code from [this site](https://crypto4ngo.org/):

```
async function myweb3_init(init) {
    var web3js;
    // Modern dapp browsers...
    if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
        try {
            // Request account access if needed
            await ethereum.enable();
            // Accounts now exposed
            init();
        } catch (error) {
            // User denied account access...
        }
    }
    // Legacy dapp browsers...
    else if (window.web3) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        // Accounts always exposed
        init();
    }
    // Non-dapp browsers...
    else {
        alert('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!');
    }
    return web3js;
}
```